# SQLite used through sqlite4java program does not end

Tags: sqlite

I have a [sqlite4java](https://bitbucket.org/almworks/sqlite4java/wiki/GettingStarted) program to connect and run statements on my SQLite database like this in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLiteException {


    getPredictions();

}

private static void getPredictions() throws SQLiteException {

    int passValue = 408;

    SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("D:\\sqlite\\CW.db"));
    db.open(true);
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM user_based_sim WHERE user1 = ? OR user2 = ?;");
    try {
        statement.bind(1,passValue);
        statement.bind(2,passValue);

        while (statement.step()) {

            System.out.println(statement.columnInt(0));
        }
    } finally {
        statement.dispose();
    }

    db.dispose();

}
```

}
The statement prints the right values etc but the program does not end, eg this remains like this until I shut it down manually:

[IntelliJ run/stop buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by2PS.png)

Looks to me the while loop doesnt halt, not sure why. I follow the documentation precisely.

Comment: You have two parameters but you only bind one of them, btw.

Comment: Does it just print out lines forever? Are all those lines values in the table?

Comment: @Shawn Yes I added another  _statement.bind(1,passValue)_. However this  did not change anything - is this the way I want to specify that I want the two parameter "?"s to be the same variable  - passValue. 

To answer your question: No, it prints the first column with values which I believe to be the right ones and it simply doesnt print anything after or do anything but does not shutdown. Makes no sense for it to NOt shutdown lol

Comment: Did you mean 2, not 1, in the second bind? You can use `?1` for both parameters in the query and only have to bind one value, btw.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, I am tired - apologies for this. Yea so now I edited the OP to showcase my code as is and the program does not terminate at all. I am certain there is not anything else apart from that code in main method of one class Main.java. That is it.

Comment: Anyways, show a minimal **complete** example program that demonstrates the issue, not just a fragment of a bigger one.

Comment: @Shawn Example edited to the complete program.  Btw if this helps, if I change the query from the OP to something more simple: "SELECT * from user_based_sim LIMIT 5;". It runs it and then it manages to terminate. Not sure why the query in the OP does this.

Comment: That's weird that it works with a limit. I'm out of ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be something else that's going on there, some other thread gets started and never terminates. Just to make sure, I ran the same code that you posted and it terminated fine. Or, possibly, there's something wrong with the database file and SQLite just keeps scanning it after the first result was printed.

To figure out what's going on, run your program in IDEA, and when it hangs in the end, use the "Dump Threads" action in IDEA (a camera-like icon). If that doesn't answer the question right away, please post the thread dump here.

Hope this helps!
Igor